# Refactor C# automatic properties to fields and getter/setter property?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a bunch of business class with autoproperties :

```
public class A {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set;}

}
```

Because the application evolves, there is a new requirement to enable tracking the changes of the properties, in order to send to the backing store only changed data.

In order to reach this goal, I have to convert ALL properties to field + property like this :

```
public class A {

    private int m_Id;
    public int Id {
        get { return m_Id; }
        set {
            if(m_Id != value){
                SetChanged("Id");
                m_Id = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private string m_Title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get { return m_Title; }
        set {
            if(m_Title != value){
                SetChanged("Title");
                m_Title = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protecte void SetChanged(string propertyName) { 
        // Not important here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to quickly refactor my code to avoid having to manually change the properties ?

Comment: If all of your business classes are simply classes with autoproperties and nothing else, I would convert to using [T4 templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to generate your classes.  Then it is a trivial change to reformat all of them as above.

Comment: Regex replace may work - also Resharper has something like this but it probably requires you to do each one in turn. Also a CodeSmith template would sort that out in no-time assuming you know how to use it. Otherwise I'd create a code snippet which has the right structure and just re-do the properties. The code snippet will filll in all the bits I suppose, but it's still a manual job! I'd go for the regex...or as mellamokb says, a T4 template, I've had good success with them for simple stuff

Comment: Do you use Resharper?  If so, it is a shortcut, and someone has extended it to automatically add INotifyPropertyChanged support: https://bitbucket.org/tgmayfield/resharper.tgmcontrib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just create a generic method that will do the assignment and call `SetChange`

```
void SetChangeIfNeeded<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
    {
        field = value;
        SetChanged(property);
    }
}
```

You would still need to have a private back field.  Your class would look something like:

```
public class A {  

    private int m_id
    public int Id 
    { 
        get { return m_id };
        set { SetChangeIfNeeded<int>(ref m_id, value, "Id"); }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Even if this will simplify the code, this will still required to manually update all properties.

Comment: I've set your answer as the solution, because I actually use this method. I've, in fact, performed some steps: First I use CodeRush XPress to refactor my autoproperty to a property with get/set over a backing field. Then, I added your method to my base class. Finally, I use Visual Studio Replace w/ Reg ex to extract : `_(\w+) = value`  by `SetValue(ref _$1, value, "$1");`. The regex match any field setter and replace it by the call to your method.

Comment: Even better: search for: `public ([\w?]+) (\w+) { get; set; }` and replace by `public $1 $2 { get{ return m_$2;} set { SetValue(ref m_$2, value, "$2");}} private $1 m_$2;`. This will avoid the refactor step, and automatically extract the autoprop.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way in the IDE to do this, but if you need to replace all X properties, I would write a short console application to do it.

The process would be:

- Iterate over all files in directory matching *.cs
- Foreach file, regex find and replace old property for new property syntax

Using regex to match is very powerful. Regex can be used in VS2010 to do a find/replace operation. If you try finding this (with regex enabled)

```
{(public|private|internal|protected)}:b{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}
:b{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}:b\{ get; set; \}
```

It will match properties like this

```
public Type Foo { get; set; }
```

In your console application find all lines of code that match the above, then start splitting them up into Modifier, Type, Property Name and finally replacing the whole block with something like this

```
// PS: this is pseudocode ;-) or could be your new property template
private [Type] m_[PropertyName].ToPascaleCase
public [Type] PropertyName
{
    get { return m_[PropertyName].ToPascaleCase; }
    set
    {
        if(m_[PropertyName].ToPascaleCase != value){
            SetChanged([PropertyName]);
            m_[PropertyName].ToPascaleCase = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I would advocate taking a backup of your code or running this test offline and testing before checking in!!

Comment: Lol, sounds like a stupid thing to say but you never know right?

Comment: I've learned to do that the first time I used notepad++ to replace all occurence of A to B in a project solution.:)

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper can do this, but wouldn't modify setter.

```
public string Title {
    get { return m_title; }
    set { m_title = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no direct way of doing this with refraction. If this was my problem. I would make code to generate this:

```
public string MakePropertyBigger(string varName, string propName, string dataType)
{
    string output = "";
    output += string.Format("private {0} {1};", dataType, varName) + Environment.NewLine;
    output += string.Format("public {0} {1}", dataType, propName) + Environment.NewLine;
    output += "{" + Environment.NewLine;
    output += string.Format("get { return {0}; }", varName) + Environment.NewLine;
    output += string.Format("set { if({0} != value){ SetChanged(\"{1}\");", varName, propName) + Environment.NewLine;
    output += string.Format("{0} = value; }", varName) + Environment.NewLine;
    output + "}" + Environment.NewLine + "}";
```

Now just plug this in and chug it out.